# Solving a random function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have that $u_{2m}$ = ${2m\choose m}$ $2^{-2m}$ and $u_{2m-2}$ = ${2m-2\choose m-1}$ $2^{-2m+2}$

what would $u_{2m-2}-u_{2m}$ = ?

I have tried writing it out explicitly and get a funny answer each time, it should be $\frac {u_{2m}}{2m-1}$

Comment: I'm sure someone will help with your question. I want to draw your attention to some problems with the title. First, one may solve an equation, but one doesn't solve a function. Second, there is nothing "random" about the objects in your question, they are very specific and well-known and well-studied expressions; randomness doesn't enter into it.

Answer (score 2):

$u_{2m}$ = ${2m\choose m}$ $2^{-2m}$ and $u_{2m-2}$ = ${2m-2\choose m-1}$ $2^{-2m+2}$

$u_{2m-2}-u_{2m} = \frac {(2m-2)!}{(m-1)!(m-1)!}2^{-2m+2}-\frac {(2m)!}{m!m!}2^{-2m} = u_{2m}(\frac{4m^2}{(2m-1)2m}-1)=u_{2m}(\frac{2m}{2m-1}-1)=u_{2m}(\frac{2m-2m+1}{2m-1})$

Comment: which is $\dfrac{u_{2m}}{2m-1}$